# Flutter Objectbox build_runner build exiting with code 78

Tags: flutter, objectbox, build-runner

I'm writing my first flutter app. I've defined the models with objectbox and now I'm trying to build objectbox codes by running `flutter pub run build_runner build`. And here's the output I get:

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 484ms

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[WARNING] ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:67:41: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
            : entityRealClass.typeValue.element!.name!,
                                        ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:158:64: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
        } else if (['Int8List', 'Uint8List'].contains(dartType.element!.name)) {
                                                               ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:160:29: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
        } else if (dartType.element!.name == 'DateTime') {
                            ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:186:60: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
            (f.type as ParameterizedType).typeArguments[0].element!.name;
                                                           ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:233:20: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
            f.type.element!.name! + (isNullable(f.type) ? '?' : '');
                   ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:416:12: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'InterfaceType'.
 - 'InterfaceType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
          .element
           ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:449:55: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
  bool isToOneRelationField(FieldElement f) => f.type.element!.name == 'ToOne';
                                                      ^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/objectbox_generator-2.0.0/lib/src/entity_resolver.dart:452:14: Error: The getter 'element' isn't defined for the class 'DartType'.
 - 'DartType' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-5.1.0/lib/dart/element/type.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'element'.
      f.type.element!.name == 'ToMany';
             ^^^^^^^
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 1.5s

[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.

pub finished with exit code 78
```

I haven't been able to find a solution online. PLEASE HELP! How can I fix this?

I've upgraded packages with `flutter pub upgrade`. A few packages updated, but the error is persistent.

Post Update:

This is my models.dart:

```
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';
import 'helper.dart';

@Entity()
class Category {
  int id = 0;

  @Index()
  String? name;

  @Backlink('category')
  var tasks = ToMany<Task>();
}

@Entity()
class Task {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;

  String? name;

  @Transient()
  TaskState state = TaskState.newly;

  int get dbState {
    return state.index;
  }

  set dbState(int val) {
    state = TaskState.values[val];
  }

  var category = ToOne<Category>();
}

@Entity()
class Day {
  int id = 0;

  @Index()
  String date = '';

  String gratitudes = '###';
  String journal = '';

  var tasks = ToMany<Task>();
}
```

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: quick_planner
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  format: ^1.2.0
  system_theme: ^2.1.0
  objectbox: ^2.0.0
  objectbox_flutter_libs: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  objectbox_generator: any

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  fonts:
    - family: comfortaa
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/comfortaa.ttf
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please share everything that one would need to reproduce your error message? Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: I updated the post. I think I added all related code, but I may be wrong. Let me know if I need to share something else? I'm very new to flutter

Comment: I'm running the code on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `analyzer` package version used (`5.1.0`) is missing the `DartType.element` method. It was fixed with `5.2.0`.

Try to run `flutter pub upgrade` to use the latest possible version.

If that won't work, use `flutter pub outdated` to see what is preventing it from  using a newer version.

Comment: A new flutter update made updating packages necessary. I was able to run the build. Thank you for responding <3